# Get date for past weekday with Smarty

Tags: php, date, smarty

I'm still fairly inexperienced with scripting, so my knowledge is limited to working with smarty.

I'm working on building a daily news site, and we are going to have an archive of news articles from every day from the past week. If the day of the week hasn't yet passed, it will show the articles from that day of the week last week. On each day's page, I want a head line that says "News from Monday, June 10th" or whatever the date for the last one of those days of the week was.

As far as I can tell, the $smarty.now function is all relative to today's date, so I can't use that. If there is any way I can do this with smarty, or if someone knows of a PHP script that I can include, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display last (past) Friday date on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111801/display-last-past-friday-date-on-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is logic that you would normally put inside your PHP script, not smarty. Try something like this:

```
empty($_GET['day']) ? $day = date('l') : $day = $_GET['day'];
$date = strtotime("last {$day}");
echo "News from ".date("l, F j", $date);
```

This script assumes that you pass the day as a GET parameter, for example index.php?day=monday. You can assign what's echo'ed to smarty. [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) are both powerful and flexible functions, have a look at their PHP documentation

Comment: This ended up being more complex than I actually needed, I just used the last two lines and since each page was url/day/, just used the variable for the day along with the strtotime() function. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!